# How to install Report Server Project Template

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, report

ive been looking for several hours but i cnat seem to get the Report Server Project in installed templates in visual studio. Im trying to follow some tutorials on pluralsight.

Comment: Please add more details to your question; what you have tried before and what didn't work for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of SQL? The Report Server Project Templete can be installed from SQL Server installation disk (2005,2008, 2008r2) or by downloading SQL Server Date Tools (2012, 2014)

Data Tools for 2012: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843
Data Tools for 2014: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027

Comment: right so i just had to install Sql Servver Date Tools .It seems that i had vs 2013 and it was out of date and didnt have SSDT installed.